# Translation of "building the sense of concern of others and what surrounds us"

Tags: phrases, translation, french

I am trying to translate a French phrase*, which literally says:

> Building the sense of concern of those and what surround us

Or, in "better" English:

> Building the sense of concern of others and what surrounds us

**Context:** 
this is a kind of "mission" for a group. 
It's supposed to include the idea of raising awareness about social and ecological responsibility. 
The idea I am trying to convey in:

- *building the sense of concern of others* should mean *caring more for the people around us*
- *building the sense of concern of what surrounds us* should mean *caring more for the environment-nature*

Does it sound OK in English?

Any other suggestions?

In French: *Contruire le souci de ceux et ce qui nous entoure*.

Comment: When you say environment, do you mean it in the sense of nature, the world around us?

Comment: Yes, you got it right! The "social environment" is already included in the "those", I only mean animals and more generally nature in the "what".

Comment: Ok. A little more context would be useful to help you further.

Comment: Thanks @user8543 for your help! I've updated my question more context.

Comment: The phrase as you have put it is unfortunately a bit cumbersome for use as a slogan. It's difficult because the two concepts (concern for others and concern for the natural world) are quite dissimilar. I'm racking my brain, however!

Comment: Caring for people and for the natural environment may look disconnected but actually they are closely related since they both require the same "empathetic skills". I really appreciate your comment, I didn't thought it could sound so dissimilar to people.

Comment: Sure, but it's a difficult concept to join in a concise way for use in a slogan :)

Comment: You're right ! I'm racking my brain on it since a couple of months!

Comment: If it's a slogan (sorry to be brief, I'm just dropping by :), give this a try, "Nurturing the care for the nature" or a more emphatic version, "Nurturing the care for our nature". If *nurture* sounds like too much, *raising* is fine too.

Comment: "Promoting anxiety about everything." (Just kidding.)

Answer (score 1):

Purely translating the phrase as I see it, given the information in the question, would give:

> Building a sense of concern for those and that which surrounds us

However, this is cumbersome at best. Something like:

> Raising awareness of the environment and those in it

would be more elegant given its intended use as a slogan.

However, it is not entirely clear who 'those in it' are. Given that 'the environment' carries connotations of the natural world, it would not be an unreasonable assumption that 'those in it' meant animals, rather than the intended sense of fellow human beings.

Edit: based on your comment regarding conveying a sense of concern, you could say:

> Promoting care for people and the environment

or simply

> Caring for people and the environment

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I really need to keep "a sense of concern for"/(or any phrase conveying the same idea) + something referring to people + something referring the environment.

Comment: Edited to reflect that